# for-loop in R, subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, for-loop

I was running the following cycle, but R does not accept it.

```
    Buy<-c(320,200,500,490,443,445,202,113,673,319) 
     Sell<-c(234,456,463,663,243,267,209,100,290,215) 
     data=cbind(Buy,Sell)

     a_i <- c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9) 
     d_j <- c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9) 
     g_n <- c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9) 
     B_bar <- mean(data[,1])
     S_bar <- mean(data[,2])

     sort_mat <- cbind(nrow=125, ncol=6)
     k <- 1
    for (i in (1:5)) {
     for (j in (1:5)) {
         for (n in (1:5)) {
              a <- a_i[i]
              d <- d_j[j]
              g <- g_n[n]
              e_b <- g*B_bar 
              u <- (B_bar-e_b)/(a*(1-d)) 
             e_s <- S_bar- (a*d*u)
              if(e_s<0){
                  k <- k+1 
                  next
              }
              in_param <-c(a,d,u,e_b,e_s)
              sort_mat[k,1] <- in_param[1] 
              sort_mat[k,2] <- in_param[2] 
              sort_mat[k,3] <- in_param[3] 
              sort_mat[k,4] <- in_param[4] 
              sort_mat[k,5] <- in_param[5] 
              k <- k+1
          }
      }
   }
        sort_mat
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, k, 3, value = in_param[3]) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

As far as I noticed, k does not increase as the resulting matrix (sort_mat) is filled with only one row (k=1). What is the potential reason of the problem? And how can I solve in the code above?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to intialise the `data frame` differently, e.g. with

```
sort_mat <- data.frame()
```

Have a look at your intial `data frame`, you have created a data frame with two columns (variables) named `nrow` and `ncol`, but you didn't set them as row or column arguments, because `data.frame` does not accept those.

```
sort_mat <- cbind(nrow=125, ncol=6)
```

```
> sort_mat
     nrow ncol
[1,]  125    6
```

Overall, is this what you are looking for (5 columns and 120 rows)?

```
> head(sort_mat)
   V1  V2        V3     V4       V5
1 0.1 0.1 3705.0000  37.05 276.9500
2 0.1 0.1 2881.6667 111.15 285.1833
3 0.1 0.1 2058.3333 185.25 293.4167
4 0.1 0.1 1235.0000 259.35 301.6500
5 0.1 0.1  411.6667 333.45 309.8833
6 0.1 0.3 4763.5714  37.05 171.0929
```